# What the reason to use Executors.defaultThreadFactory().newThread?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, executor

In our project I faced following method:

```
Thread t = Executors.defaultThreadFactory().newThread(new MyRunnable(importStartedTimestamp));
t.setName("my thread");
t.start();
```

I am wrong or first line is full analog of

```
Thread t = new Thread(new MyRunnable(importStartedTimestamp));
```

Please explain if first code snippet has advantages.

### P.S.

I don't like to create redundant entities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right. `Executors.defaultThreadFactory().newThread().start()` is verbose.

The better use case for `ThreadFactory` is in `Executors`. `ThreadFactory` is accepted as argument, such as `newCachedThreadPool(ThreadFactory threadFactory)`. In such case, you could change the `ThreadFactory` instance argument with changing client code.

Answer (score 2):

From [Java 7 docs ( Executors#defaultThreadFactory() )](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#defaultThreadFactory()):

> **Returns a default thread factory used to create new threads. This
>   factory creates all new threads used by an Executor in the same
>   ThreadGroup.** If there is a SecurityManager, it uses the group of
>   System.getSecurityManager(), else the group of the thread invoking
>   this defaultThreadFactory method. Each new thread is created as a
>   non-daemon thread with priority set to the smaller of
>   Thread.NORM_PRIORITY and the maximum priority permitted in the thread
>   group. New threads have names accessible via Thread.getName() of
>   pool-N-thread-M, where N is the sequence number of this factory, and M
>   is the sequence number of the thread created by this factory.

Basically this is a factory interface for creating threads for a [ThreadGroup](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadGroup.html). Of course you can do this by hand (as your second code snippet shows, and a few more lines if you need special settings eg.), but the factory method was designed to hide all the details you might need.

Also it eliminates the need to call `new Thread()` directly so you can use Runnable and any of its subclasses also.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that defaultThreadFactory creates meaningful names so at time of debugging or profiling you see names like pool-2-thread-3 which makes it easy to follow.
Check this out
http://javahowto.blogspot.com/2011/11/why-use-threadfactory.html

Answer (score 1):

Here's one that nobody else mentioned:

If you are writing a library that will be used by other programs, and if your library needs to create Threads or thread pools, then it should use a ThreadFactory *that is supplied by the client program*.

If the client program chooses not to provide one, then that's when you use Executors.defaultThreadFactory().

Giving the client the option to be notified of/control Thread creation and the option to provide custom Threads will make your library more attractive to potential clients.

Answer (score 0):

Also, priority and `daemon`-property are reset to default by factory.

```
if (t.isDaemon())
    t.setDaemon(false);
if (t.getPriority() != Thread.NORM_PRIORITY)
    t.setPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY);
```

`new Thread()` would inherit these properties from parent thread. Probably, that's the case. Factory code may be called from a thread with non-default priority or from daemon thread.

Answer (score 0):

Two differences as far as I can see:

The names are different:
new Thread():

> Automatically generated names are of the form "Thread-"+n, where n is an integer.

DefaultFactory:

> New threads have names accessible via Thread.getName() of pool-N-thread-M, where N is the sequence number of this factory, and M is the sequence number of the thread created by this factory.

Also, the set priority is slightly different. new Thread():

> The priority of the newly created thread is set equal to the priority of the thread creating it, that is, the currently running thread.

defaultFactory:

> [...] with priority set to the smaller of Thread.NORM_PRIORITY and the maximum priority permitted in the thread group

Answer (score 0):

newThread(Runnable r)  method does:

1. Setup ThreadGroup
2. Setup new thread name
3. Setup stack size (will ignored)
4. Set  as daemon (if it's daemon)
5. Set priority to Thread.NORM_PRIORITY;

### Source

```
/**
 * The default thread factory
 */
static class DefaultThreadFactory implements ThreadFactory {
    private static final AtomicInteger poolNumber = new AtomicInteger(1);
    private final ThreadGroup group;
    private final AtomicInteger threadNumber = new AtomicInteger(1);
    private final String namePrefix;

    DefaultThreadFactory() {
        SecurityManager s = System.getSecurityManager();
        group = (s != null) ? s.getThreadGroup() :
                              Thread.currentThread().getThreadGroup();
        namePrefix = "pool-" +
                      poolNumber.getAndIncrement() +
                     "-thread-";
    }

    public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
        Thread t = new Thread(group, r,
                              namePrefix + threadNumber.getAndIncrement(),
                              0);
        if (t.isDaemon())
            t.setDaemon(false);
        if (t.getPriority() != Thread.NORM_PRIORITY)
            t.setPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY);
        return t;
    }
}
```